# Memory Issues with Python/Jython subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess, jython

I'm running a subprocess with a jython script. I don't receive a return code and instead have to scan the stdout for a string with the timeout error number.

I'm finding this to be very slow, and am not sure if there's a better way to go about it. I've tried nulling the pointers to the `rc, out, err` variables before the `time.sleep(5)` and also tried increasing the `time.sleep(30)`. What else could I try to reduce the memory usage?

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'path/to/some/other/process'

tries = 3
def timeout_check(out, tries):
    for i in range(tries):
        rc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=STDOUT, stderr=Err)
        out, err = rc.communicate()
        if 'Error 1234: Timeout Error Message' not in out:
            if rc.returncode == 0:
                if out and len(out) > 0:
                    print(out)
                    break
            else:
                if out and len(out) > 0:
                    print(out)
                raise Exception('The process failed with non-zero return code')
        else:
            print('Timeout! Will re-try...')
            time.sleep(5)
    else:
        raise Exception('Cannot start process, tried %i times' % tries)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try an explict "rc.terminate()" before the "time.sleep(5)".  Apart from that, I would suggest profiling and/or dumping the heap to see where the memory is being used.  I presume the buffers which communicate() writes to are filling up.